# How does one map an array in order to create both a new array with changed array items but without mutating the original array or any of its items?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, mapping, shallow-copy

I have an array of objects for example I want to replace the key normal with value `www.test.com/is/images/383773?@HT_dtImage`. I am using `.replace` with regex to basically replace the `wid and hei` with `@HT_dtImage`

```
const urls = [
{"normal": "www.test.com/is/images/383773?wid=200&hei=200", 
"thumbnail": "www.test.com/is/images/383773?wid=200&hei=200"},
{"normal": "www.test.com/is/images/383773?wid=200&hei=200",
 "thumbnail": "www.test.com/is/images/383773?wid=200&hei=200"},
{"normal": "www.test.com/is/images/383773?wid=200&hei=200",
 "thumbnail": "www.test.com/is/images/383773?wid=200&hei=200"}
]
```

I tried using a `.map` like this which just returns the original object.

```
const updateImages = images => {
  images.map(image => {
    return image.normal.replace(/\b(?:wid|hei)=[^&]*&?/g, "") + "@HT_dtImage"
  });
  return images;
};
```

I also tried this but it returns it in an array without not as an array with objects. I feel like I'm just missing something simple.

```
const updateImages = images => {
   return images.map(image => {
     return image.normal.replace(/\b(?:wid|hei)=[^&]*&?/g, "") + "@HT_dtImage"
  })
};
```

The expected output I am looking for is

```
const urls = [
{"normal": "www.test.com/is/images/383773?@HT_dtImage", 
"thumbnail": "www.test.com/is/images/383773?wid=200&hei=200"},
{"normal": "www.test.com/is/images/383773?@HT_dtImage",
 "thumbnail": "www.test.com/is/images/383773?wid=200&hei=200"},
{"normal": "www.test.com/is/images/383773?@HT_dtImage",
 "thumbnail": "www.test.com/is/images/383773?wid=200&hei=200"}
]
```

Comment: You are asking how to replace the value with "333" but in your code you are using a regular expression that does something completely different. What are you intending to do?

Comment: Haven't had my coffee yet. I updated the post it should make sense now

Comment: Are you trying to update the objects in the array, or return a *new* array with the `@HT_dtImage`s in it, while leaving the original one unchanged?

Comment: @Tyler I am trying to return a new array with the `@HT_dtImage` in it while leaving the original input `images` unchanged.

Comment: In case the OP intentionally wants to mutate every of the original array's url item, then `map` was not the right method but `forEach` was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP not only needs to [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the original array but also has to create and return a shallow **[1]** (and accordingly changed) copy of each array item.

***[1]** which for the OP's use case is sufficient enough due to not having to deal with deeper nested object/data structures.*

Thus one could  ...

- either utilize [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#examples)
- or one makes use of [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#syntax) ...

```js
const getNewListOfUpdatedUrlItems = itemList => {
  return itemList.map(item => {
    return {
      // create shallow `item` copy.
      ...item,
      // change `item` copy's `normal` property accordingly.
      normal: item.normal.replace(/\b(?:wid|hei)=[^&]*&?/g, "@HT_dtImage"),
    };
  });
};

const urlItemList = [{
  "normal": "www.test.com/is/images/383773?wid=200&hei=200",
  "thumbnail": "www.test.com/is/images/383773?wid=200&hei=200",
}, {
  "normal": "www.test.com/is/images/383773?wid=200&hei=200",
  "thumbnail": "www.test.com/is/images/383773?wid=200&hei=200",
}, {
  "normal": "www.test.com/is/images/383773?wid=200&hei=200",
  "thumbnail": "www.test.com/is/images/383773?wid=200&hei=200",
}];
const newUrlItemList = getNewListOfUpdatedUrlItems(urlItemList);

console.log({ newUrlItemList, urlItemList });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

In case the OP intentionally wants to mutate every of the original array's url item, then `map` was not the right method but [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) was ...

```js
function changeUrlNormal(urlItem) {
  urlItem.normal =
    urlItem.normal.replace(/\b(?:wid|hei)=[^&]*&?/g, "@HT_dtImage");
}

const urlItemList = [{
  "normal": "www.test.com/is/images/383773?wid=200&hei=200",
  "thumbnail": "www.test.com/is/images/383773?wid=200&hei=200",
}, {
  "normal": "www.test.com/is/images/383773?wid=200&hei=200",
  "thumbnail": "www.test.com/is/images/383773?wid=200&hei=200",
}, {
  "normal": "www.test.com/is/images/383773?wid=200&hei=200",
  "thumbnail": "www.test.com/is/images/383773?wid=200&hei=200",
}];

urlItemList.forEach(changeUrlNormal);

console.log({ urlItemList });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks, Peter just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

On your first try, `images.map` returns a new array which you don't assign to anything. You are returning the same array as the one passed as parameter.

```js
const newImages = images.map(....);
return newImages
```

Comment: The explanation is partially correct. But a valid solution is missing. (btw ... I didn't downvote)

Comment: Yes my answer was to "I tried using a .map like this which just returns the original object." which is normal with his code. Don't know why the downvote anyway :p

Answer (score 0):

```
  let mapped_urls = urls.map((url) => {
    url.normal.replace(/\b(?:wid|hei)=[^&]*&?/g, '') + '@HT_dtImage';
    return url;
  });

  console.log('URLs', mapped_urls);
```

```js
 const urls = [
    {
      normal: 'www.test.com/is/images/383773?wid=200&hei=200',
      thumbnail: 'www.test.com/is/images/383773?wid=200&hei=200',
    },
    {
      normal: 'www.test.com/is/images/383773?wid=200&hei=200',
      thumbnail: 'www.test.com/is/images/383773?wid=200&hei=200',
    },
    {
      normal: 'www.test.com/is/images/383773?wid=200&hei=200',
      thumbnail: 'www.test.com/is/images/383773?wid=200&hei=200',
    },
  ];

  let mapped_urls = urls.map((url) => {
    url.normal =
      url.normal.replace(/\b(?:wid|hei)=[^&]*&?/g, '') + '@HT_dtImage';
    return url;
  });

  console.log('URLs', mapped_urls);
```

Here's your output :

[image]

Comment: The above code does not only create a new array of changed url items but it does mutate the original array's url items as well.

Answer (score 0):

You neen to return an array with some object that have the needed key, so something like:

```
const updateImages = images => images.map(image => (
  {
     ...image,
     normal: image.normal.replace(/\b(?:wid|hei)=[^&]*&?/g, "") + "@HT_dtImage",
  }
);
```